# Powershell requirement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a requirement. We have a FTP server where the data will change everyday. There are around 9 files. Each file is data for MS SQL ETL. Now what i want to do is. As soon as file arrives in FTP location. Powershell should read that date modified of the file and trigger the job in SQL Server. Is that possible with powershell?

Challenges involved

1. Limited with technology (Only powershell and TSQL Can be used)
2. Old file (Day - 1) Data. to get each file completely replace it
   will take 15 Minutee,  before that job should not triggered.

Need your inputs on this.

Comment: What's the question? Is this possible? Yes, it's possible. Anything is possible. What work have you done toward solving the problem, and where are you getting stuck? Is PowerShell a requirement, or have you already decided to use it before determining if it's the most appropriate solution?

Comment: We need to have something to go on. Post as much of your code as you can, if it's broken, someone might be able to help you. However, if you want someone to do your homework for you then no one here will look twice at your question

Comment: To add to alroc's comments, I don't know if PowerShell is your best option here.. Also, Server OS / PS Version help when you're asking these types of questions. You *can* create a FileSystemWatcher, however, liked I said, doing this from PowerShell is probably not the best option. A service would most likely be better.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a FileSystemWatcher. A similar-ish question has been asked before, so I won't try to regurgitate the answer:

[Watch file for changes and run command with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell)

See also on MSDN:

- [FileSystemWatcher class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [FileSystemWatcher events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=vs.110).aspx)