# How to start a FileSystemWatcher when the window shell starts

Tags: windows, shell, filesystemwatcher

I want to create a shell extension and I need it to respond to events like file created. I know how to use the FileSystemWatcher class but I don't know how to make sure it gets initialized when the shell does. Is there a good way to do this or am I better of creating an application that starts on startup and have it communicate with the shell extension?

Comment: Write a separate application. Managed code is not supported in shell extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a task that starts every 5 minutes and looks if a previous instance is already running. The task will start at reboot and a program crash or even a scheduled exit at midnight.
See [solution with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell) for some other ideas.