# Tracking last modified date on a large file share

Tags: powershell

I have a file share that takes hours to scan. Recently I have been asked to make a script that can send a mail when over 100 files has been changed within one minute. How can I go about his? Could be powershell, could be anything that would enable such a "scan".

Comment: "takes hours to scan". What do you mean by "scan", and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have worked on finding permission groups on this file share. Running through every folder on the file share and looking up the ACL took hours.
So far I have tried nothing because I can't wrap my head around how I can keep track of change in files that have been change by the minute, when the share takes hours to "scan".

Comment: You don't need to retrieve the ACL every time if you're only interested in changes to the file itself

Comment: I think we're talking past each other. I simply wanted to elaborate on what I meant by "hours to scan". I am not currently looking for ACL, that was a previous assignment. I am curious how I can check like every 5th minute if over 100 files where changed within the same interval, like a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to run every 5 minutes, you could retrieve all files with a `LastWriteTime` property value less than 5 minutes old, then group the files by the minute:

```
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$FilesPerMinute = Get-ChildItem C:\folder\share -Recurse |Where-Object { 
  $_.LastWriteTime -ge $Threshold 
} |Group-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Minute } -NoElement
if($FilesPerMinute |Where {$_.Count -ge 100}){
    # alert
}
```

---

You might find that a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell/29067433#29067433) is a better option in your scenario though

Comment: I will try this! Thank you

Comment: The file share that I'm trying to track is over 4 TB of folders and files. So this probably won't finish in 5 minutes, can you think of any thing that might do this? Perhaps FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Yes, auditing - turn on file system auditing, parse the security log file every minute to see if more than 100 files were modified