# Powershell - Listen for file, do something if file exists

Tags: powershell, filesystems, actionlistener

Is there a way in Powershell to "listen" for a file?

In jQuery (for text fields), you can do something like this:

```
$("#textarea").on("change",function () { // do something });
```

This catches the change **instantly**.

I've seen code like this:

`while (!(Test-Path "C:\flag.txt")) { Start-Sleep 1 }`

But this seems ineffiecient; this is constantly checking for the file, and it would not be instantaneous ( 1 second between checks).

Comment: Looks like you want a FileSystemWatcher, kind of like the one available on the gallery here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell