# How can I update my AWS Lambda function from VSCode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

So I have an AWS Lambda function written in NodeJS, but I am tired of coding in the AWS Console or having to manually zip my code in my VSCode to manually upload it in he AWS Console.

I know that I can update my function with `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file "fileb://myZipFile"`. But how can I zip it and launch this command every time I save my work in VSCode ?

Also, I am on Windows.

Comment: Powershell can monitor folders for changes. The top voted answer would seem to accomplish what you’re looking to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell/29067433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without some additional work.

A few options are:

- use the [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) VS Code extension and configure a custom command to run when a file is saved
- create a [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) project and install the [AWS Toolkit for VS Code](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/) extension to provide [deployment assistance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/deploy-serverless-app.html)
- create a package.json that includes a script for zip/deployment and use the [NPM extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.vscode-npm-script) for VS Code to execute the deploy script
- build a CI/CD solution: use VS Code to commit and push your code, then the pipeline takes over and deploys it
- use a shell script, or a Makefile with a target, that zips and deploys and then simply execute it, manually or otherwise, in the VS Code in-built terminal

Answer (score 0):

I use a script with below and run it when need to update.

```
echo "Building zip file"
zip -rq testfunction.zip testfunctionfolder/

echo "update Lambda function"
FUNCTION_ARN=$(aws lambda update-function-code \
  --function-name testfunction \
  --zip-file fileb://testfunction.zip \
  --query 'FunctionArn' \
  --output text)

echo "Lambda function updated with ARN ${FUNCTION_ARN}"
```