# How to check if downloaded file exists or not using powershell

Tags: powershell

Folks,
I have an scenario to check if downloaded file exists or not in my system using powershell, I used Test-Path it works for me in single command, but we need to check in loop.Please help me to resolve.

Test-Path -path C:\Users\Documents\Deployment\ABC.zip

Comment: Try and see if a [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7) loop would work for you.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "we need to check in loop". Otherwise we can't help you...

Comment: Take a look at systemfilewatcher. Plenty of examples on SO, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that ?

```
$logos = @('D:\Temp\Logos\Access.jpg', 'D:\Temp\Logos\Excel.jpg', 'D:\Temp\Logos\xxxxx.jpg', 'D:\Temp\Logos\Oracle.jpg')

foreach($l in $logos){

    Write-Host $l
    Test-Path -path $l

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the asker wants to query in a loop while the file doesn't exist, but it's rather unclear what is meant.