# Powershell and Task Scheduler - Trigger script if file directory has not changed since last 30 minutes

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0, windows-task-scheduler

I've following code to trigger $powershell_code_to_run when file location is not updated for last 30 mins. However, Script is not triggering `Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe'` or `Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\calc.exe'`.

My `$task` variable is coming blank. Not sure if that's an issue

```
    $powershell_code_to_run = {
    # ALL CODE TO RUN GOES HERE
    $DIR = "C:\Scripts\ASA"
        Write-Host "Start"
    $LastWriteTime = (Get-Item $Dir).LastWriteTime

    IF ($LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)) {
        Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\calc.exe'
    } ELSE {
        Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe'
    }
    # AND END HERE.
}

# Base64 encode code to run.
$encodedCommand = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($powershell_code_to_run.ToString()))
$encodedCommand
# Action, using EncodedCommand removes the need to escape quotes etc.
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand"
$action
# Task trigger                                  Start :00 next hour                             Repeat every 30 minutes, repeat forever
$triggers = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ((Get-Date)) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30)
# $triggers = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ([datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(1)) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 2)

Write-Host "Triggers"
$triggers
# Settings for the task.
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable
$settings
# Other settings
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -RunLevel Highest -UserId "LOCALSERVICE" -LogonType ServiceAccount
$principal
# Name of the task
$taskName = 'Check folder for changes'
$taskName
# The actual task object
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Settings $settings -Trigger $triggers -Description 'Check a folder if there has been any changes in the last 30 minutes.' -Principal $principal
$task
# Remove the old task
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#  Create new
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $task -TaskPath '\'
```

Comment: Have you considered doing something like [this other, older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell)?

Comment: I was told that is not an efficient way of doing it.