# Run commands based on file content

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write a script on Windows that does the following:

1. Reads (or tails) a file and waits for specific content to be found.
2. Run some commands if the specific content is written to the file.

What I came up with is something like this:

```
$logPath="C:\ProgramData\myapp\conn.log"
$oauthPath="C:\ProgramData\myapp\OAuthSettings"
Get-Content $logPath -Wait -Tail 1 | Select-String "java.io.InvalidClassException"

# If `java.io.InvalidClassException` is written to the `conn.log`:
# Delete OAuthSettings file
Remove-Item $oauthPath

# Restart service to clear cache
Restart-Service myapp.service
```

The problem is, I don't know how to 'fuse' the `Get-Content` bit with the other commands. From what I understand `Get-Content` leaves the file open and checks it's content once a second.

Comment: I guess you really want to use a [FileSistemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher). There are many examples on this to be found, for examlpe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the line does not have time to appear due to the fact that the $ logPath file is occupied at this moment by the previous iteration of get-content?