# Run python scripts in Power Automate

Tags: python, azure-functions, power-automate

I use Power Automate to fetch some data from SQL database and save them into different excel files. After my workflow is done, I have 8 different excel file, and I need to do some data preprocessing on them. I've got the python script which consists of various libraries such as pandas etc. and does the job but I need to make it automate.

What I want is basically after my workflow is done, running the python script automatically with Power Automate.

I read some articles about it such as [article1](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Execute-python-script-from-Power-Automate-Flow/td-p/550328). Is there any other way except using the azure functions? Because it seems a bit complex and it's only free for 12 months.

Comment: My first approach would be to drop the excel files into a blob storage container and have your azure function trigger on new blobs arriving to the container.

Comment: So your suggestion is simply to create an Azure function... Can you review 5th of 6 messages in [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Execute-python-script-from-Power-Automate-Flow/td-p/550328) topic. Do you think that it'd be the solution?

Comment: I belive that what he is doing is watching for file changes onthe one drive folder synced on his computer. The watch runs a script when a file shows up. That's at least what I understand from his answer. That could be okay, but it does require you to have your computer running 24/7 (or a VM with the synced onedrive folder).

Using azure functions allows you to forget about that.

 Also it's free for 12 months but if you are processing just a few small files a day the cost will be literally pennies.

Comment: This might be helpful if you opt for the solution on the forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell

Comment: Thanks a lot @GuillemB , sorry for late reply I was in a hurry. I think I go with azure solution.

Comment: @RutkayKarabulak may I ask, how did you solve your concern? I am in a similar project, I have a excel file with multiple tabs and multiple formulas, I tried to keep making formulas for their solution, but it seems a little bit odd and outdated. An automate python file would be the best solution for me.

PD. the azure function option looks complicated.

Comment: @AndresMitre Hi, I solved my problem as following; I implemented a python script that solves my problem, afterwards I published my python script via Azure so that it will run everyday, if you ask what I used as a trigger to run python code my answer is Power Automate. Power automate was triggering my azure code every day.

However, if I were old me I would basically use the windows's task scheduler to run my code daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can just use azure function to run python script in power automate. I think the best solution is use azure function which you are using now.

For you concern about cost, you can create the function with a free app service plan (if your requirements do not need high performance）. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost) about app service plan.

[image]

Even though you don't choose free app service plan, it will not cost much more if you choose [consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan) for your function.