# How to check file size using Windows batch?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to make a detection script for checking file size changes. But I'm still very new to Windows batch scripting, and I just can't get it working...

The function that I wanted to achieve:
Detect and store imported file size and compare it to the new file size for every 3 seconds. If size changes do `echo Change detected!`. Else, run `echo Not yet...`

```
@echo off
set "FOLDER=%~1"
set "DesktopINI=%FOLDER%\desktop.ini" 

for /f %%A in (%DesktopINI%) do set "ImportSizee=%%~zA" // Store the current file size.

:LOOP
for /f %%A in (%DesktopINI%) do set "CheckSize=%%~zA" // Check and set new file size every 3 second.
if !CheckSize! GTR !ImportSize! (
    echo Change detected!
    timeout /t 3
    exit
) else (
    echo not yet...
)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
goto :LOOP
```

Where do I needs to change?

Comment: Comment out the `@echo off` line at the top and you'll see what's going on step by step. Btw, there is a typo in `do set "ImportSizee=%%~zA"`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that at all... Thanks for the advice!!

Comment: I don't think polling for file size like that is a good idea. You should watch a file for size change event which isn't easy in cmd but trival in powershell: [Watch file for changes and run command with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29066742/995714). Another downside of cmd is that it only supports 32-bit integers so it'll break if there's a file larger than 2GB