# How to watch a file, whenever it changes, take the new additional line and perform some actions on it with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

How can I watch a log file and each time a line is added to it, I want to reformat that line and broadcast it to a webhook using Invoke-RestMethod (basically using discord as a log file) then possibly also output some/same info to the console.

This is a similar question to others asked like it.  I've been trying to do this for 2 weeks.  In the following post they answered most of this question:

[Watch file for changes and run command with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell)

However, it does not show how to take the added line to the file and perform actions on it all while it is still waiting for the log file to be updated again with the next entry.  Log files can be updated fast in succession so not sure if these methods will keep up with the change if another change comes to the log file while the program is performing said action on the detected change.

So far, I was trying with something like this in a loop (this is not the entire code):

```
get-content '<file-name>' -tail 1 -wait
```

But It looks like this may miss lines in succession as while it's processing the additional actions, more lines may come in.  So it looks like I may need to do this in a much more complicated way (which is okay).  Just trying to figure out which direction to go.

Any suggestions or direction to go are much appreciated.  Even a link if that's what it takes.

Comment: Kinda new to Powershell so there may easily be a very obvious way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is only allowed to show a file in real-time on the screen. You cannot mess with the output doing that.

The command you are using is not for interactive use cases.

You can monitor for file updates without doing what you are doing, by using a SystemFileWatcher, which allows for monitor for file actions, that you can then take action on.

---

> 'PowerShell filesystemwatcher monitor file'
>
> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+filesystemwatcher+monitor+file%27&t=h_&ia=web

---

For example from one of the hits from the above link.

> https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher
>
> Monitoring Folders for File Changes
>
> With a FileSystemWatcher, you can monitor folders for file changes and
> respond immediately when changes are detected. This way, you can
> create “drop” folders and respond to log file changes.

Specifically, as per your use case:

> ***Advanced Mode (asynchonous)***
>
> If you expect changes to happen in rapid succession or even
> simultaneously, you can use the FileSystemWatcher in asynchronous
> mode: the FileSystemWatcher now works in the background and no longer
> blocks PowerShell. Instead, whenever a change occurs, an event is
> raised. So with this approach, you get a queue and won’t miss any
> change.
>
> On the back side, this approach has two challenges:

- Handling Events: since PowerShell is single-threaded by nature, it is
  not trivial to respond to events, and even more cumbersome to debug
  event handler code.

  Keeping PowerShell running: ironically, because the FileSystemWatcher
  now no longer blocks PowerShell, this leads to another problem. You
  need to keep PowerShell waiting for events but you cannot use
  Start-Sleep or and endless loop because as long as PowerShell is busy

  - and it is considered busy even if it sleeps - no events can be handled.

> Implementation
>
> The script below does the exact same thing as the synchronous version
> from above, only it is event-based and won’t miss any events anymore:

```
# find the path to the desktop folder:
$desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

# specify the path to the folder you want to monitor:
$Path = $desktop

# specify which files you want to monitor
$FileFilter = '*'  

# specify whether you want to monitor subfolders as well:
$IncludeSubfolders = $true

# specify the file or folder properties you want to monitor:
$AttributeFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName, [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite 

try
{
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = $Path
    Filter = $FileFilter
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }

  # define the code that should execute when a change occurs:
  $action = {
    # the code is receiving this to work with:
    
    # change type information:
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $Name = $details.Name
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    
    # type of change:
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    
    # when the change occured:
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    
    # save information to a global variable for testing purposes
    # so you can examine it later
    # MAKE SURE YOU REMOVE THIS IN PRODUCTION!
    $global:all = $details
    
    # now you can define some action to take based on the
    # details about the change event:
    
    # let's compose a message:
    $text = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $FullPath, $ChangeType, $Timestamp
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
    
    # you can also execute code based on change type here:
    switch ($ChangeType)
    {
      'Changed'  { "CHANGE" }
      'Created'  { "CREATED"}
      'Deleted'  { "DELETED"
        # to illustrate that ALL changes are picked up even if
        # handling an event takes a lot of time, we artifically
        # extend the time the handler needs whenever a file is deleted
        Write-Host "Deletion Handler Start" -ForegroundColor Gray
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 4    
        Write-Host "Deletion Handler End" -ForegroundColor Gray
      }
      'Renamed'  { 
        # this executes only when a file was renamed
        $text = "File {0} was renamed to {1}" -f $OldName, $Name
        Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow
      }
        
      # any unhandled change types surface here:
      default   { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White }
    }
  }

  # subscribe your event handler to all event types that are
  # important to you. Do this as a scriptblock so all returned
  # event handlers can be easily stored in $handlers:
  $handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed  -Action $action 
  }

  # monitoring starts now:
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

  Write-Host "Watching for changes to $Path"

  # since the FileSystemWatcher is no longer blocking PowerShell
  # we need a way to pause PowerShell while being responsive to
  # incoming events. Use an endless loop to keep PowerShell busy:
  do
  {
    # Wait-Event waits for a second and stays responsive to events
    # Start-Sleep in contrast would NOT work and ignore incoming events
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1

    # write a dot to indicate we are still monitoring:
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
        
  } while ($true)
}
finally
{
  # this gets executed when user presses CTRL+C:
  
  # stop monitoring
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
  
  # remove the event handlers
  $handlers | ForEach-Object {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.Name
  }
  
  # event handlers are technically implemented as a special kind
  # of background job, so remove the jobs now:
  $handlers | Remove-Job
  
  # properly dispose the FileSystemWatcher:
  $watcher.Dispose()
  
  Write-Warning "Event Handler disabled, monitoring ends."
}
```

So, with the above, you tweak it to look for updates/modifications, then use

```
$CaptureLine = Get-Content -Path 'UNCToTheLogFile' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Or

```
$CaptureLine = Get-Content -Path  'D:\temp\book1.csv' -Tail 1
```

And do what you want from that.