# Powershell clear terminal get-contant?

Tags: powershell

I want to display the actual content of a txt file.
if i use

```
get-content txt.txt  -wait
```

i will get

```
1
2
9
```

i add 10 and see

```
1
2
9
10
```

i add 3 and see

```
1
2
9
10
3
9
10
```

It would be great if on refresh the output would be cleared and i see the hole file not fragments of actuall file and the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear the terminal before watching the file, use:

```sh
Clear-Host
Get-Content 'txt.txt'  -wait
```

To only see the last few lines instead of the whole file, use `-Tail N`:

```sh
Get-Content 'txt.txt'  -wait -Tail 10
```

Or to see no existing lines from the file at all, use `-Tail 0`

Comment: would be nice to have a clear-host everytime it refreshes to see the whole file

Comment: @maf There's nothing built-in, but you can use a `[IO.FileSystemWatcher]` to monitor a file for changes and trigger a new `Clear-Host; Get-Content`. See this answer for details/examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067433/7411885