# My boss for work asked me to create a powershell script to send email notifications when a new file is added or a file has been changed

Tags: powershell

I've been searching online about this script and I've only found this so far

I don't know anything about scripting but I've tried to implement this on my pc and I haven't received any emails whenever I added a file to my test folder. help with this would be much appreciated.

P.S if you're going to explain something to me about scripting, act like you're explaining to a 5 year old because I'm clueless when it comes to scripting lol

```
Param (
    [string]$Path = "C:\Users\ahmad.mahmoud\Desktop\test",
    [string]$SMTPServer = "smtp.domain.com",
    [string]$From = "email@domain.com",
    [string]$To = "email@domain.com",
    [string]$Subject = "new file added"
    )

$SMTPMessage = @{
To = $To
From = $From
Subject = "$Subject at $Path"
Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}

$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1) }
If ($File)
{   $SMTPBody = "`nThe following files have recently been added/changed:`n`n"
    $File | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n" }
    Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
}
```

I tried to implement the code above in PowerShell but I didn't get any email notifications whenever I added a new file to my test file (of course I changed the email and stmp server address due to privacy reasons.)

Comment: The script does several things, do you know which one exactly does not work? Is it new file presence detection? Is it sending an email? Something else? You should figure that out first.

Comment: I will try figuring that out and getting back to you

Comment: @AhmadMahmoud you probably want to also check for a file's `CreationTime`, since copied files keep the same `LastWriteTime`, then set up a scheduled task to run it every minute. The classic way to watch a folder for changes is here, but is more complex to deal with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067433/7411885